# Add top and bottom padding to UILabel using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

How do you add padding to the top and bottom of the content within a `UILabel`?

I have tried to find the means of doing it via `NSAttributedString` text but cannot seem to find a way to apply margins to the top and bottom only.

Comment: Why not add some space between the label and its neighbors?

Comment: Should have mentioned but it's embedded within a tableview cell.

Comment: Doesn't the cell use Auto Layout (and self-sizing)?

Comment: Yes but the content is programatically added and varies with different amounts of text, some are multi-lined and so appear at the ever edge of the cell.

Comment: Do you have a visual example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in swift :-

```
class Label: UILabel {
    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)))
    }
}
```

Comment: how to implement it?

Comment: You can directly use this as custom class through storyboard .